# How do you extract all the javascript code from a user control in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extract, code-behind

On the PreRender event of my page, I decide to do a `response.redirect()`.
That means none of the javascript enclosed in `<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">` tags on that page are executed.

I wish to do the below :

```
String allJavaScript = MagicFunctionThatReturnsAllJSInTheControl(someUserControl)

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock("".GetType(), "s", allJavaScript );

Response.Redirect("~/newpage.aspx",false);
```

Do you know how would one code up, in C#/vb.net the  `MagicFunctionThatReturnsAllJSInTheControl(someUserControl)`

Thanks

Comment: `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` only renders `<script>` elements in the current page, no more. So even if what you wish was possible, you still would have to somehow pass `allJavascript` to `newpage.aspx` for that page to execute it. Since you're redirecting, you would have to use either the query string or the user's session. The result would probably not be pretty.

Comment: Not really, the ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock will execute it on currentpage.aspx before the browser redirects to newpage.aspx

Comment: Well, no. RegisterClientScriptBlock() will schedule a `<script>` element for rendering in the current page, then `Response.Redirect()` will proceed to forget about the whole page and send a `302` header to the client. Maybe you were thinking about `Server.Transfer()`?

Comment: @trainer scripts run when the response has ended, so if you are doing a `response.redirect`, then the current response's scripts will not be processed...

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi => Script code as you mentioned should execute once the control will move out from the function and even after the page life cycle and in case of not moving to another page as other user mentioned about `response.redirect`. In case move to other page in the same function, does it make sense to render the script tag on the page which is about to expire... ?

Comment: @Pankaj, it's *client* code we're talking about. It does not execute on the server, but within the user's web browser. Therefore, it won't be executed when control leaves `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`, or `Render()`, or even `ProcessRequestMain()`. It will be rendered within the page so the client can execute it, but if that content never leaves the server, as with `Response.Redirect()`, the client will never see or execute it.

Comment: Both of you(FH and BM) are right. I got that above piece of code but had not tested it out.
I created a small dummy site, and it did not work.

So i now have 2 problems :(

Comment: @trainer, what are these scripts supposed to do? Is there no way to externalize them into a `js` file and have both the original page and `newpage.aspx` refer to that file?

Comment: well most of the code is in an external js file. And both the pages use that js file. However the js variables' values in the js code are set(in the code behind) based on some logic in each page.
The same code (but with different values in the variables) has to execute on both the pages.
Currently it only executes on the newpage.aspx and not on the currentpage.aspx because of the response.redirect. I need it to run on currentpage before it goes to newpage and executes again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In light of your last comment, I think I have a possible solution, even if it does not answer your question as originally stated.

So, you want scripts in `currentpage.aspx` to execute on the client even though you're in the process of redirecting it to `newpage.aspx`. In this situation, you can avoid `Response.Redirect()` and perform the redirection on the client:

```
string redirectScript = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    "window.location.href = '{0}';", ResolveUrl("~/newpage.aspx"));

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "redirectScript",
    redirectScript, true);
```

This way, the client should load the page and execute the scripts within, then load `newpage.aspx`. If you can stand the original page to be briefly visible while the redirected page loads, this might solve your problem.

Comment: This may not work as is.  [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bahh2fef.aspx): "The script blocks are not guaranteed to be output in the order they are registered".  If this second script is output first, the redirection will happen immediately and the other scripts will never execute.

Comment: @gilly3, I don't think the questioner actually wants to call `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` with the scripts that are part of the markup if he can execute them directly (the code in your answer actually ends up rendering these scripts twice, assuming `MagicFunctionThatReturnsAllJSInTheControl()` behaves as intended). The scripts that are part of the markup will always run before the ones registered through `RegisterClientScriptBlock()`, however, so using that to redirect should be safe. If there are other calls to `RegisterClientScriptBlock()` in the code, though, your point stands.